# Is the ReverseLookup zones important to a DNS server?

Tags: networking, reverse-dns

We simply have none. I am a humble software programmer, with insignificant networking knowledge, but there are not any network admins to turn to where I work. I looked at the DNS server out of curiosity and found the zones are not even defined, much less populated. We use Win Server 2003

Thanks.

Marshall

Comment: MS' "official" stance: `Reverse lookup zones and PTR resource records are not necessary for Active Directory to work, but you need them if you want clients to be able to resolve FQDNs from IP addresses. Also, PTR resource records are commonly used by some applications to verify the identities of clients.` -- basically if you haven't identified a need for a RLu zone, then you probably don't need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't important to a DNS server itself. They can be important to a sytems administrator, but whether they are or not is mostly a matter of opinion. They are important to some (but by no means all) software packages - some packages require forward and reverse lookups to match (i.e. name 'foo' maps to IP address 'x.y.z.w', which reverse maps to name 'foo').

Comment: Thank you. I like to be thorough, and would choose to do so, even though it's apparently optional (depending on the environment, as indicated) but it seems I don't have an argument to convince my boss to set them up.

Comment: You could always try the catch-all "I need PTR records for client verification and security purposes", but that's not guaranteed to get you anywhere but into the "paranoiac" bucket. :)

Comment: Is there any reasons or any cases where they would be a _bad_ idea?

Comment: I can't think of any off-hand.